# asymmetrically encrypt string, save encrypted string and public key to property file to be read by different program

Tags: java, encryption-asymmetric

I have a string that will be saved to .properties file that I do not want changed by a user. The .properties file is meant to be sent to that other user and at run time pull up the string that I do not want changed. my current solution is to symmetrically encrypt the string and save both the encrypted string and the the key to the .properties file which will then be decrypted at run time. The issue with this approach is that if the user decompiles the .class files, he can clearly see the method with which the string was encrypted (in this case the initiation vector for "AES" encryption) and repeat the encryption process with a different string, completely bypassing the security measure.
Is there a way to encrypt the string asymmetrically while still saving the public key with the encrypted string to the properties file for decryption at run time? From what I have read I think I need to use RSA, but everything I have found deals with public and private key objects which I do not think can be written to a properties file. Any help is greatly appreciated (even a completely different solution that using RSA)
Thank You!

Comment: What is the approximate size of the string that you want to protect? What is the business case of this requirement? Is it necessary to use a properties file?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is that you want to ensure the value in the property file has not been modified (by the end user or anyone else), you can use a private key to sign the value. In the app that is distributed to the user, include the signed value and the public key in the properties file (not the private key).

In the app distributed to the user, use the public key to verify that the signed value was signed with the private key. If the value was modified, the verification of the signature with the public key will fail, so you know the value has been changed.

There's a chapter in the Java Tutorial that shows how to do this with classes provided in java.security : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html